# Laravel 5.5. - Property [xxxx] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I created two methods that make sql requests that i want to share to all views in my backoffice :

```
public function getEntities()
{
    $vcs = Valuechain::select('valuechains.id', 'lang_valuechain.vcname', 'lang_valuechain.vcshortname')
        ->withCount('segments')
        ->join('sectors', 'valuechains.sector_id', '=', 'sectors.id')
        ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
        ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
        ->where('langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1')
        ->whereNull('valuechains.deleted_at')
        ->whereNull('sectors.deleted_at')
        ->get();

    return $vcs;
}

public function getEntitiesWithKeyneeds()
{
    $valuechains = Valuechain::orderBy('valuechains.id')
        ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
        ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
        ->where('langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1')
        ->with('segments')
        ->with('keyneeds')
        ->withCount('segments')
        ->withCount('keyneeds')
        ->get();


    foreach ($valuechains as $valuechain) {
        $ids[] = $valuechain->id;
    }

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $vcskns[] = Segment::select(
            'lang_valuechain.vcname', 'lang_valuechain.vcshortname',
            'lang_segment.segname', 'lang_segment.segshortname', 'segments.id',
            'lang_segment.created_at', 'lang_segment.updated_at', 'lang_segment.deleted_at'
        )
            ->distinct()
            ->withCount('keyneeds')
            ->join('lang_segment', 'segments.id', '=', 'lang_segment.segment_id')
            ->join('valuechains', 'segments.valuechain_id', '=', 'valuechains.id')
            ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
            ->join('sectors', 'valuechains.sector_id', '=', 'sectors.id')
            ->join('lang_sector', 'sectors.id', '=', 'lang_sector.sector_id')
            ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
            ->where([
                ['langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1'],
                ['valuechains.id', '=', $id]
            ])
            ->whereNull('valuechains.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('sectors.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('segments.deleted_at')
            ->get();

    }
    return $vcskns;
}
```

I call this method in another method which returns a view :

```
public function index(EntityInterface $vcs)
{
    $entitiesLists = $vcs->getEntities();
    $entitiesWithKnLists = $vcs->getEntitiesWithKeyneeds();

    return view('admin.home', compact('entitiesLists', 'entitiesWithKnLists'));
}
```

I have a var_dump which returns for entitiesWithKnLists :

```
[
   {
        "vcname":"VC1",
        "vcshortname":"VC1",
        "segname":"S1",
        "segshortname":"S1",
        "id":1,
        "created_at":"2018-06-07 09:18:31",
        "updated_at":"2018-06-07 09:18:31",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "keyneeds_count":0
    },
   {
        "vcname":"VC1",
        "vcshortname":"VC1",
        "segname":"S2",
        "segshortname":"S2",
        ... 
    },
   {
        "vcname":"VC2",
        "vcshortname":"VC2",
        "segname":"S3",
        "segshortname":"S3",
        ... 
    },
]
```

In my view vcname is repeated and i want to display it only once so I wrote in my view the following code :

```
@foreach($entitiesWithKnLists as $entitiesWithKnList)
    {{ $entitiesWithKnList->first()->vcname  }}<br>
@endforeach
```

It returns the correct values I expect.

When i want to display "segname" as we can see in the var_dump, I just write something similar :

```
@foreach($entitiesWithKnLists as $entitiesWithKnList)
    {{ $entitiesWithKnList->segname  }}
@endforeach
```

I obtain an error message :

Property [segname] does not exist on this collection instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue this way :

```
@foreach($entitiesWithKnLists as $entitiesWithKnList)
    {{ $entitiesWithKnList->first()->vcname }}
    @for ($i=0; $i< count($entitiesWithKnList); $i++ )
        {{  $entitiesWithKnList[$i]->segname }}
    @endfor
@endforeach
```